# Global objects with joblib

Tags: python, joblib

I would like to better understand how *joblib* handles global objects. Consider following simple example.

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

class Engine:
  def f(self, x):
    return x+2

engine = Engine()

def run_engine(x):
    return engine.f(x)

def main():
    res = Parallel(n_jobs=5)(delayed(run_engine)(x) for x in range(0,100))
    print(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What is going to happen to `engine` object? Is it going to be copied or somehow shared by all spawned processes?

If copied, are there any serialization requirements? And how many times will it be copied, `n_jobs` times or once per each call to `run_engine`? Are all objects in the scope copied or does *joblib* somehow magically infer which are necessary?